# Regexp::Debugger Perl module doesn't seem to work within another Perl Module

Tags: regex, perl, debugging, perl-module

I am writing a Perl module that involves some very complicated regular expressions that are nearly impossible to debug without a tool to help me. I figured the [`Regexp::Debugger`](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Regexp-Debugger-0.002000/lib/Regexp/Debugger.pm) module would be the perfect tool for the job, but it only seems to work in `.pl` scripts and doesn't seem to work within a `.pm` module.

---

For example, this works:

**test.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Regexp::Debugger;

my $text = "text";
if ($text =~ /tex/) {
    print "Match!";
}
```

And I get the expected debugging functionality.

---

But the second I introduce a Perl Module to the mix it no longer works:

**test.pl**

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use TestModule;

TestModule::func();
```

**TestModule.pm**

```
package TestModule;

use strict;
use warnings;
use Regexp::Debugger;

sub func {
    my $text = "text";
    if ($text =~ /tex/) {
        print "Match!";
    }
}

1;
```

Attempting to run this code gives the following error:

> Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference at Regexp/Debugger.pm line 160

Simply including `Regexp::Debugger` in the "test.pl" file instead doesn't work either because it doesn't try to debug regexes within included modules.

How can I get this to work so I can debug the regexes within a module that I'm working on?

---

### UPDATE:

A bug report has been filed, and a new version (v0.002001) is now available on CPAN that works as expected. :)

Comment: I find that loading it at runtime (`require` + `->import`) in modules shows no errors and 'normal' code works -- but the module doesn't seem to do any of its job.

Comment: It seems that there is a bug in the debugger... >.<

Comment: OK -- it did look weird.  A good find!  Should probably be reported

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the way Regexp::Debugger checks lexical hints in calling scopes, but I'm not sure how to fix it. For reference, https://metacpan.org/source/DCONWAY/Regexp-Debugger-0.002000/lib/Regexp/Debugger.pm#L160 is:

```
my $lexical_scope = (caller 1)[10]{'Regexp::Debugger::lexical_scope'};
```

Maybe it should do `((caller 1)[10] || {})->{'Regexp::Debugger::lexical_scope'}` instead?

---

Anyway, I was able to reproduce your problem and I found a workaround. In `test.pl`, do:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
no Regexp::Debugger;
use TestModule;
```

I.e. load `Regexp::Debugger` before you `use TestModule`, but with `no` instead of `use` to avoid activating it for the main program.

With this change, I get:

```
TestModule.pm did not return a true value at test.pl line 4.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 4.
```

... which is still an error, but it's a good error. It means there were no problems with `Regexp::Debugger`.

If I then add a line of `1` at the end of `TestModule.pm`, everything works.

---

*Update:* OP [reported the problem](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=123134) and [it was fixed](https://metacpan.org/changes/distribution/Regexp-Debugger#L233-236) in version 0.002001 of Regexp::Debugger.